# why this eventListner callback function is running twice

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener, event-listener

```js
const addons = document.querySelectorAll('.addon');
const toggleAddon = (e, addon) => {
  console.log(addon);
  console.log(addon.querySelector('input').checked);
  if (addon.querySelector('input').checked)
    addon.classList.remove('selected-plan');
  else addon.classList.add('selected-plan');
};

addons.forEach((addon) => {
  addon.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleAddon(e, addon));
});
```

```html
<label>
    <div class="addon addon-2 selected-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" name="addon-2" class="addon-chkbox" id="larger-storage">
        <div class="addon-info">
            <h3 class="addon-name">Larger Storage</h3>
            <p class="addon-features">Extra 1TB of cloud save</p>
        </div>
        <div class="addon-pricing-box">
            <h3 class="addon-pricing">$2/mo</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

Why when I click on this element, the function `toggleAddon()` runs twice and in first run `console.log(addon.querySelector('input').checked)` comes `false` and on second it comes `true`.
Thanks for the help.

This is another simplified example that will better show what I'm pointing out:

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelector('.addon')
  .addEventListener('click', event =>{
    console.log(`[${++counter}]`);
    console.log(event.target);
  });
```

```html
<label>
  <div class="addon">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="addon-info">
      <h3 class="addon-name">Click here</h3>            
    </div>        
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: The only reason why an event handler would run twice for the same event is if it was bound twice (and really this also only happens if you bind two different function instances, you cannot bind the same function twice for the same event).

Comment: I think it's the combination of having a wrapping label and an input control. The click action will also automatically dispatch another click event targeting the input control (you can see it echoing the event.target value). You can also make the example simpler using a very easy event handler with no third function and without doing any logic inside but just console logging the event target. The ripetition doesn't occur if you remove or the label or the input control

Comment: I don't see that it runs twice in stackoverflow snippet runner

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer it does. Click on the header element

Comment: You can use the change event instead of the click event (unless you care about IE)

Comment: Now I partially understand what's happening and what can be done to solve this but according to @CherryDT by changing event from click to change, it's working perfect. I still don't fully understand, have to drain my mind to get this. What's IE here

Comment: Internet Explorer - the thing is that IE fired change events only when the focus was removed from the checkbox and it value had since changed (like the change event works in textboxes), not when it was actually clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `<label>` element, when it is clicked, it trigger another `click` event on the `input` element within.

I suggest using `change` event instead.

[check it in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weird-title-v2mpk1).

Answer (score 1):

The whole label is for the input? so why not listen to the input click event only which will automatically be handled by the label? like:

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelector('.addon-input')
  .addEventListener('click', event =>{
    console.log(`[${++counter}]`);
    console.log(event.target);
  });
```

```html
<label>
  <div class="addon">
    <input class="addon-input" type="checkbox">
    <div class="addon-info">
      <h3 class="addon-name">Click here</h3>            
    </div>        
  </div>
</label>
```